# How to condense values from 150 1536 well plates into one value per coordinate in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, matrix

I have 150 32 by 48 matrices of values that represent color intensities from images of yeast plates.  I would like to take for example coordinate (x,y) from each plate generate an average and then create a new plate out of that.  Right now I have all of the values in a file in the following format:

- EA_D01_5-8   30,22   -0.397914165526517
- EA_D01_5-8   30,23   -0.326759277147352
- EA_D01_5-8   31,22   -0.172657520010773
- EA_D01_5-8   31,23   -0.103405885199075

The first group represents the plate name the second the x,y coordinates and the third the z-score value.

```
while($line = <DATAFILE>){                 
     chomp($line); 
     my @temp = split(/\t/, $line);
     $long_name = $temp[0];
     $coords = $temp[1];
     $zscores = $temp[2];
     $stats{$long_name}{$coords}[0] = $zscores;
```

`}`

I have created a hash $stats{$long_name}{$coords}[0] to store the values
I then created a loop to try to gain access to those values:

```
foreach $long_name ( sort keys %stats ) {

        foreach $coords( keys %{$stats{$long_name}} ){

                my $zscoreV = $stats{$long_name}{$coords}[0];
                $totalV = $totalV + $zscoreV;

        }
```

}

However I am doing something wrong because when I try to divide the total by 150 being the number of unique values in $long_name I am not left with 1536 values.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want.  I think you want an "average" plate, where 0,0 has the average of the 0,0 values of all 150 plates, 0,1 has the average of the 0,1 values, etc.

If so, you don't want a hash by long name, you want just a hash by coords:

```
my %coords_total;
my %coords_count;
while(my $line = <DATAFILE>) {
    chomp($line); 
    my ($long_name, $coords, $zscores) = split(/\t/, $line);
    $coords_total{$coords} += $zscores;
    $coords_count{$coords}++;
}

my %coords_average = map $coords_total{$_} / $coords_count{$_}, keys %coords_total;
```

(Assuming an arbitrary number of plates; if you always want to assume 150 plates, you can just do `$coords_average{$coords} += $zscores / 150;` in the initial loop.)